Core php - change routing system for my api project
I have one project developed in core php. it is complete backend system like only apis are developed here. All files like user.php , user_city.php all are inside project directory. now I want to move files inside users folder like users/user.php or user_city.php but dont want to change the api path. Like www.example.com/user.php should redirect to www.example.com/users/user.php.

You will need to do something at the server level first, Nginx, Apache, IIS, etc. Either redirect specific individual routes, or have a catch-all rule that redirects to a PHP-based router (my preference).

you can use url rewrite in apache

you can also keep existing files and move code of users.php file to  users/users.php and include this file inside users.php  ex:   include "./users/users.php" ;

Depending on your webserver, you can configure it to send 301 responses and redirect those requests to desired location. Bear in mind, that your API consumers can have their code set in a way, that those redirects are ignored and their implementation could throw errors. It is advised to communicate these changes to the prior making them.
Other option is not to redirect the user but map the URL to different folder on your server. The URL on which is the content available wouldn't change.

Redirect in Apache: How to redirect in apache?
Rewrite in Apache: RewriteRule ^user\.php$ /users/user.php [L]

